# Cannot find name 'withStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
 import * as React from "react";
 import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
 import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
 import {WithStyles} from '@material-ui/core';
 import "./App.css";
 import PageTwo from "./components/PageTwo";
   const styles = theme => ({
   container: {
   display: "flex",
   flexWrap: "wrap"
   },
   textField: {
   marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
   marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
   width: 200
   },
   menu: {
   width: 200
   }
  });

export interface Items {
objectID?: string;
URL?: string;
}
export interface IPropsk {
data?: Array<Items>;
fetchData?(value: string): void;

}
export interface IState {
 isLoaded: boolean;
 hits: Array<Items>;
 value: string;
}

 const API = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=";

 export class App extends React.Component<IPropsk, IState> {
 constructor(props: IPropsk) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
     isLoaded: false,
     hits: [],
     value: ""
 };

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 }

  fetchData = event => {
  fetch(API + event)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits }));
 };

 handleChange(event) {
 this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
 }
 render() {

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <TextField
        id="required"
        label="Required"
        defaultValue="Hello World"
        margin="dense"
        value={this.state.value}

        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />

      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => this.fetchData(this.state.value)}
      >
        Search
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <PageTwo data={this.state.hits} />
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}


export default withStyles(styles);
```

I  wrote above code snippet to call method fetchData From button click .It works Fine with out erros. But when I Apply MateriaUI to change the style of the  components(I just want to put a space between button and the TextField) I get the following error even I import WithStyles .It comes from the last line.

```
  Cannot find name 'withStyles
```

Comment: Hi Chameera, I've had a look at your codeSandbox and it works for me. When I add `border: '1px solid red',` to button in styles, the red border appears around the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import

`import {WithStyles} from '@material-ui/core';`

needs to be changed to

`import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `WithStyles` notice the `W` is capped, use

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Replace the bottom line to the below and it should work.

```
export default withStyles(styles);
```

Comment: I tried not  working.Here is the example I m trying https://codesandbox.io/s/53ok610wql

Answer (score 0):

i think you need install the core module to add it to dependencies,

`npm install @material-ui/core`

or

`yarn add @material-ui/core`

thanks